# Como saber em qual posição uma incógnita está localizada em um vetor?

Tags: r

Exemplo:

```
a=c(10,9,8,7)
b<-max(a)
a[b]
```

Preciso saber em que posição b está localizado no vetor a,o R deve retornar 1 (que é a resposta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dê uma olhada na função `which()`:

```
a=c(10,9,8,7)
b<-max(a)
a[b]
which(a == b)
# [1] 1
```

Outras opções é a função `match()`:

```
match(b, a)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado,estou no meio de um código gigantesco para um trabalho e não sabia desse comando básico! Grato!

Answer (score 4):

Outra maneira de resolver é com a função `which.max`:

```
a=c(10,9,8,7)
which.max(a)
[1] 1
```